# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de un registro en una relación consigo mismo en Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm

establecí una tabla con relación a ella misma de esta forma en la migración:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('zones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('initials')->unique();

        $table->integer('zone_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('zone_type_id')->references('id')->on('zone_types');

        $table->integer('zone_id')->nullable()->default(null)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('zone_id')->references('id')->on('zones');


        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

(con la que tengo problemas es con zone_id) Es una tabla para establecer la relación entre zonas (por ejemplo que departamentos pertenecen a que país).

Cuando estoy creando un registro de zona que no tenga asociada una otra zona se crea correctamente (porque definí que la llave foranea podría ser nulla), pero cuando creo un registro asociando otro (por ejemplo creo un departamento y le asocio un pais) la vista me muestra el siguiente error:

**Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reservationSystem/resources/views/configuracion/zone/index.blade.php)**

Esta esa la definición del modelo:

```
class Zone extends Model
{
  protected $table = "zones";
  protected $fillable = ['initials','name','zone_type_id','zone_id'];

  public function zone_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Zone_type');
  }

  public function zoneChildren(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Zone');
  }

  public function zoneFather(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Zone');
  }
}
```

y la vista, estoy llamando el método de la relación para intentar obtener el nombre de la zona asociada al registro pero arroja el error que menciono arriba

```
@extends('shared.main')
@section('title','Configuración/Zona')

@section('content')

<a href="{{ route('zona.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</a>
<hr>    
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Iniciales</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Tipo zona</th>
        <th>Padre</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($zones as $zone)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $zone->initials }}</td>
                <td>{{ $zone->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $zone->zone_type->name }}</td>
                @if($zone->zone_id == null)
                    <td>{{ $zone->zone_id}}</td>
                @else
                    <td>{{ $zone->zoneFather->name }}</td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-warning separate_left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" onclick="return confirm('¿Desea eliminar el tipo de identificación?')" class="btn btn-danger separate_left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

{{ $zones->links() }}
@endsection
```

Espero haberme hecho entender y que puedan darme una mano, creo que básicamente el problema radica en cómo mostrar el nombre de la zona asociada al registro de otra zona en la vista usando las relaciones del ORM de laravel (Creo que estoy usando correctamente las relaciones según la documentación) porque como tal el modelo de datos está correcto en mi base de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge por que estás llamando a una clave que no está definida `$zone->zoneFather->name` si puedes observar, en tal caso deberías de llamar `$zone->zoneFather()->name` para que la misma función te retorne el valor de dicha clave, míralo del lado de la programación orientada a objetos